# Real connection between bxslider and the url

Tags: javascript, html, bxslider

Is it possible get a **real connection between bxslider and the url** like the following examples?

```
www.domain.com/#slide-01
www.domain.com/#slide-02
www.domain.com/#slide-03
```

The **url should update** if the user change the slide and it also would be nice to drive bxslider by the `url + #Anchor`. If the user type `www.domain.com/#slide-02` it should display the second slide.

```
<div class="bxslider-images">
      <div id="slide-01"><img src="image_01.jpg" border="0"></div>
      <div id="slide-02"><img src="image_02.jpg" border="0"></div>
      <div id="slide-03"><img src="image_03.jpg" border="0"></div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** With the help of **baao** the slider is now driven by the `id's of the slides`, but sadly it is out of sync, even though the URL is correct now, it skipps the 2nd slide.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var sliderImages = $('.bxslider-images').bxSlider({

        pager:false,
        startSlide: 0,
        infiniteLoop: false,
        onSlideNext: doThis,
        onSlidePrev: doThis,

    });

    function doThis(element, old, newslide){
        var urlWithoutAnchor = document.URL.replace(/#.*$/, "");
        var newUrl = urlWithoutAnchor + '#' + element.attr('id');
        console.log(newUrl);
        window.location = newUrl;
        sliderImages.goToSlide(newslide);

    }

});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've edited my answer, can you please check if this does what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with this code:

```
var url = window.location.href;
if (url == 'http://www.domain.com/') // or whatever it is
{
window.location.href = url + '#slide-01'; // etc...
}
```

within your slide function!

**EDIT:**

I don't use bxslider, so I'm not 100% sure if this will work, but it might fit your needs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


var url = window.location.href;

var slide = url.split('#');
    if (slide[1]) {


var slidenumber = slide[1].replace(/([a-z,0,/-])/g, '');
    }

if (!slidenumber) { slidenumber = 0;}


var sliderContent = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
     pager:false,
     startSlide: slidenumber,
     var urlWithoutAnchor = document.URL.replace(/#.*$/, "");
     //location.hash.replace('#','')
     window.location.href = urlWithoutAnchor + '#' + newslide;
});

});
```

Comment: Thanks @baao! But after a few clicks the url looks like this: /index.html#2#0#2

Comment: Ah you're right, you can put it in a if statement, I edit it in my answer

Comment: I think this might be better. You can also delete anything after the # before you run the function, might be the better solution

Comment: Thanks again! Yes, because your code only works one times. I will try it!

Comment: I've tried to removed the anchor, it seems to work, but i would be nice to have a real connection to bxslider so that bxslider is driven by the url.

Comment: Tested your ideas the whole day and I made some progress in terms of connecting the url to the slides. After that, I don't think it is necessary to have a startslide. Nevertheless, there is one last bug in "url rewriting" that I have not found today.